# Dynamically added names to an array inside a template

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add and values to an array dynamically and have them populate. However I cannot even get a console.log statement to be printed. I am a little confused on why I am not getting an error or a console.log statement.

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').
controller("Controller",["$scope", function($scope){

    $scope.customer = [

         {
            name: 'Drew',
            age: 30
         },

         {
            name: 'Meike',
            age: 54
         },

        {
            name: 'Peter',
            age: 25
        },
        {
            name: 'Alex',
            age: 44
        }
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function(customer_name,customer_age){

        var person = {
            name: customer_name,
            age: customer_age
        };

        customer.add(person);

        console.log("You added a person "+person.name+" who is "+person.age+" years old.");
    }

}])
    .directive("myNames",function(){
        return{
            restrict : 'E',
            transclude : false,
            templateUrl: 'pages/myNames.html',
            scope: {
                listcustomers: "="
            }
        };
    });
```

template:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in listcustomers">

    <table class="box-table" width="100%">
         <tr>
           <th>Name:{{customer.name}}</th>
           <th>Age:{{customer.age}}</th>
         </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter a name" ng-model="customer_name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter a age" ng-model="customer_age">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="addCustomer(customer_name,customer_age)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
      <my-names listcustomers='customer'></my-names>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `addCustomer` function to the template like this

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
      <my-names listcustomers='customer' add-customer='addCustomer'></my-names>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry that did not work. For some reason ng-click is not responding.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo. Try `add-customer` instead of `addCustomer`. See my  updated answer.

Comment: Still nothing. I even tried to remove the variables from ng-click because intellij is telling me "unresolved variable" and that didn't seem to do anything.